# wp_editor - Media uploader button to tinymce

Tags: tinymce

I want to add a button to TinyMCE editor, which opens Media Uploader of WordPress. I have used `wp_editor()`. Here is my code-

```
$editor = array(
    'textarea_name' => 'message',
    'media_buttons' => false,
    'textarea_rows' => 8,
    'quicktags'     => false,
    'drag_drop_upload' => true,
    'tinymce'       => array(
        'paste_as_text'                 => true,
        'paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste'   => true,
        'paste_remove_spans'            => true,
        'paste_remove_styles'           => true,
        'paste_remove_styles_if_webkit' => true,
        'paste_strip_class_attributes'  => true,
        'toolbar1'                      => 'bold italic | superscript subscript | bullist numlist | forecolor backcolor | link unlink | image media | visualblocks undo redo code',
        'toolbar2'                      => '',
        'toolbar3'                      => '',
        'toolbar4'                      => ''
        ),
    );

wp_editor( '', 'message', $editor );
```

I want an icon to be shown here-
[image]

How do I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Still not an easy in WordPres. you will have to [create an MCE editor plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Buttons#Creating_an_MCE_Editor_Plugin) that uses the [WordPress media uploader](https://mikejolley.com/2012/12/21/using-the-new-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-plugins/).

An easier workaround is to create a very simple MCE editor plugin that added an icon who's only purpose will be to trigger a click on the 'Add Media' button. And that button;remove the `media_buttons` parameter from your `wp_editor()` arguments so that the button is shown, but then you hide it with CSS.

Comment: I have tried in this way, enabled media button and hidden it with CSS. And then added a TinyMCE button which triggers a click on the 'Add Media' button.

Everything is working fine in the wp-admin area. But the new button is not showing up in the frontend. I'm using this `wp_editor()` in  page with a shortcode.

In wp-admin area- http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/1095/1729595626.png

In frontend- http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/1095/3542075871.png

Comment: Try the different hooks: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/mce_buttons,_mce_buttons_2,_mce_buttons_3,_mce_buttons_4

Comment: thanks for idea but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend just enabling the built-in media button by setting:

```
'media_buttons' => true
```

It will place the button above the toolbar but it's a very simple solution.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question but +1 for the practical answer, note that `media _buttons` is true by default, so he only has to remove it, but he did it in purpose, he wants a button in the tool bar, just like he asked.

Comment: @NabilKadimi, you are right.